# Why does DbContext.Entry(IEnumerable<MedicalProduct>).State produce an ArguementNullException in my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my `MedicalProductController`, I am trying to make my `Edit` action able to edit multiple objects on one page.  To do that, I plan on my `HTTPPOST` edit action method receiving an `IEnumerable<MedicalProduct>` instead of the `MedicalProduct` that the scaffolding set up for me.

When I click save to submit some changes, I get an `ArguementNullException` unhandled on the line: `_db.Entry(productList).State = EntityState.Modified;` and I don't understand why it is null.

### MedicalProductController:

```
public class MedicalProductController : Controller
{
    private MvcMedicalStoreDb _db = new MvcMedicalStoreDb();

    // some code omitted for brevity

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        MedicalProduct product = _db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var productList = new List<MedicalProduct> { product }; 
        var viewModel = GetMedicalProductViewModelList(productList);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> productList)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Entry(productList).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //var productList = new List<MedicalProduct> { product };
        var viewModel = GetMedicalProductViewModelList(productList);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

}
```

### Edit.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MedicalProduct</legend>

        @foreach (var modelItem in Model)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(item => modelItem.ID)

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(item => modelItem.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(item => modelItem.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => modelItem.Name)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(item => modelItem.Price)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(item => modelItem.Price)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => modelItem.Price)
            </div>


            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(item => modelItem.BrandName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(item => modelItem.BrandName, modelItem.BrandSelectListItem)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => modelItem.BrandName)
            </div>
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: I would have expected an `InvalidOperationException` stating that `productList` is not part of the model. Because that's what seems to be wrong here: you should set the state of the individual `Product`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the model binder isn't able to bind to your collection, which would cause it to be `null`.  The reason it's doing that is because you're not specifying an index for each of the elements.  That means MVC has no way to determine how to bind them correctly.

### Edit

I've figured out why the last revision of this answer didn't work.  Firstly, `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have a direct indexer.  Instead you would use `Model.ElementAt(i).ID` to access the `ID` property.  However, this actually wouldn't solve the problem with the model binding issue as, for some reason, this doesn't generate the proper indices on the `name` attributes for the generated `<input>` fields. (More on this below.)

There are two ways to fix that.  The first way would be to pass a `List` to the view, instead of `IEnumerable`, then accessing the fields as I showed earlier.  However, the better way would be to create an `EditorTemplate` instead.  This will be easier because it saves you having to change your existing methods which are generating your view model.  So you'll need to follow these steps:

1. Create an `EditorTemplates` folder inside your view's current folder (e.g. if your view is `Home\Index.cshtml`, create the folder `Home\EditorTemplates`).
2. Create a strongly-typed view in that directory with the name that matches your model (e.g in this case the view would be called `MedicalProductViewModel`).
3. Move the bulk of your original view into that new template.

You'll end up with the following:

```
@model MedicalProductViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.ID)

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.Price)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Price)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Price)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.BrandName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(item => Model.BrandName, Model.BrandSelectListItem)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.BrandName)
</div>
```

Notice how we're no longer using any indexing notation to access the model properties.

Now in your `Edit.cshtml` view, you'd be left with this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MedicalProduct</legend>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Although I gave a brief explanation at the start, I should really explain what this is actually doing.  Your original HTML would have produced output like the following:

```
<input name="ID" type="text" value="1" />
<input name="Name" type="text" value="Name 1" />
<input name="ID" type="text" value="2" />
<input name="Name" type="text" value="Name 2" />
```

As you can see, multiple input fields share the same name.  That's why the model binder is tripping up, because your action is telling it to bind to a collection and the binder needs to be able to distinguish between each element in the collection.  `EditorTemplates` are smart enough to figure out when you're working with a collection and will apply indices to your input fields automatically.  What the code above will do is generate output like this instead:

```
<input name="[0].ID" type="text" value="1" />
<input name="[0].Name" type="text" value="Name 1" />
<input name="[1].ID" type="text" value="2" />
<input name="[1].Name" type="text" value="Name 2" />
```

As you can see, the fields now have an index associated with them.  That gives the model binder all the information it needs to be able to add all of the items to the collection.  Now that's out of the way, we can get back to fixing your product saving code.

What Gert said is still right about the way you're trying to save `productList`.  You need to be setting the `EntityState.Modified` flag on each individual item in that collection:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    foreach (var product in productList)
        _db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

See if that works.

Comment: When I use that code in my cshtml file, I get a compilation error: 

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel>'

Comment: @ArmorCode Updated my answer.  Hopefully this will work for you now.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand.  How does the compiler know to take what's in that editor template file and put it in `Html.Editorfor(m=> m)`?  My understanding is that the strongly typed `@model IEnumerable<MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel>` tells the view it should expect an ienumerable for what goes into "m" of EditorFor.

Comment: @ArmorCode The `@model` directive is only dictating what model the current view must be passed.  As the current view is being passed an `IEnumerable` it means that when calling the helper like so, `Html.EditorFor(m => m)`, it's simply being passed the entire `IEnumerable`.  The helper, under the hood, is able to distinguish between when it's being passed a single type and when it's being passed a collection.  In this case, it will repeatedly invoke the relevant template for every element in the collection, which also generates the proper indices for the HTML output.

Comment: Hm.. strange, when I apply the code you posted, my page displays only the literal ID property of the MedicalProduct I selected to edit, but it should be displaying the fields that can be edited.  The view file I made is under "Views\MedicalProduct\EditTemplates\MedicalProductViewModel.cshtml"  Where MedicalProduct is the controller, and EditTemplates is the new folder I created.

Comment: @ArmorCode Sorry, typographical error on my part.  Rename your `EditTemplates` folder to `EditorTemplates`.  That should fix it.

Comment: I understand, it worked. I didn't know that "EditorTemplates" was the designated folder name.  I thought you were just making one up.  Do I use the same folder if I want to enable the user to create and delete multiple files on the same view?

Comment: @ArmorCode You can use it for whatever you wish.  The only requirement is that any template in that folder must have the same name as the type it represents.  The reason for that is because the templates are looked up based on the type that is passed to the HTML helpers.

Comment: @ArmorCode Incidentally, I should mention that `DisplayTemplates` also exist, which are used by the `Html.Display*` helpers.  They're exactly like the `EditorTemplates` except you'd store them in a folder called `DisplayTemplates`, instead of `EditorTemplates`.  I'd recommend reading Brad Wilson's article series about the topic (found here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).  Although it's using MVC 2, most of that still applies.  The only things that differ are the syntax in the templates and their extension (.ascx instead of .cshtml).

Comment: @ArmorCode So did that answer your question?