# Why is my view not using my EditorTemplates folder for my create action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my `MedicalProductController`, I am trying to make my `Create` and `Delete` actions able to create and delete multiple objects on one page by passing `IEnumerable<ViewModel>` to the view. The approach I am using with my `Create` action worked with my `Edit` Action in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122873/why-does-dbcontext-entryienumerablemedicalproduct-state-produce-an-arguement/19123206?noredirect=1#comment28307488_19123206).  But it is not working with my `create` action, so I suspect something isn't right.

The problem is that no fields appear on the page.  The page simply says: "Create", "Save" (button), "Back to list" (a clickable link) on that page.  In-between "Create" and "Save" there should be the html editor fields and labels created by MedicalProductViewModel.cshtml shown below.

Here is what my setup looks like.

### Create.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MedicalProduct</legend>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m)        
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

### Views\MedicalProduct\EditorTemplates\MedicalProductViewModel.cshtml

```
@model MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.ID)


<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.Price)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Price)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Price)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.ID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(item => Model.BrandID, Model.BrandSelectListItem)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.BrandID)
</div>
```

### MedicalProductController.cs

```
public class MedicalProductController : Controller
{
    private MvcMedicalStoreDb _db = new MvcMedicalStoreDb();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var productList = _db.Products.ToArray();

        var viewModelList = GetMedicalProductViewModelList(productList);
        return View(viewModelList);
    }

    public IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> GetMedicalProductViewModelList(IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> productList)
    {
        var brandList = _db.Brands.ToArray();

        var mapper = new MedicalProductMapper();

        return mapper.MapMedicalProductViewModel(productList, brandList);            
    }
    public IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> GetMedicalProductList(IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> viewModelList)
    {
        var mapper = new MedicalProductMapper();

        return mapper.MapMedicalProductList(viewModelList);
    }

    //
    // GET: /MedicalSupply/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /MedicalSupply/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public ActionResult Create(MedicalProduct medicalProduct)
    public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> productViewModelList)
    {
        var productList = GetMedicalProductList(productViewModelList);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (MedicalProduct product in productList)
                _db.Products.Add(product);

            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(productViewModelList);
    }
}
```

### MedicalProductMapper.cs

```
public class MedicalProductMapper
{

    public IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> MapMedicalProductViewModel(IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> productList, IEnumerable<Brand> brandList)
    {            
        var brandSelectListItem = brandList.Select(b => new SelectListItem()
                                                {
                                                    Text = b.Name,
                                                    Value = b.ID.ToString()
                                                });

        var viewModelList = productList.Select(p => new MedicalProductViewModel() 
                                {
                                    BrandID = p.BrandID,
                                    //BrandName = brandList.SingleOrDefault(b => b.ID == p.BrandID).Name,
                                    BrandSelectListItem = brandSelectListItem,
                                    ID = p.ID,
                                    Price = p.Price,
                                    Name = p.Name
                                });

        return viewModelList;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> MapMedicalProductList(IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> viewModelList)
    {
        var modelList = viewModelList.ToArray().Select( viewModel => new MedicalProduct()
        {
            Name = viewModel.Name,
            Price = viewModel.Price,
            BrandID = viewModel.BrandID
        });

        return modelList;
    }
}
```

### EDIT

My edit view is very similar to my create view:

### EDIT.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MedicalProduct</legend>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m)        
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Why do you have an `IEnumerable` instead of just one model?  Is that so the user can add multiple records in one submission?

Comment: @McGarnagle Yes, Also, it enables me to make less calls to the database, because more models can be processed inside a single function call, without needing to escape the function, and retrieve another model, and I can use the same code without having to make a new function that accepts a single MedicalProductViewModel.  I was trying to make things simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Create() controller method is passing a null to your view, hence the editortemplate doesn't fire.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

If you pass in a new List<>, then it will work like your editor.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new List<MedicalProductViewModel>() { new MedicalProductViewModel() });
}
```

Is there a reason why you aren't just passing in a single viewmodel instead of a list? You will be able to use your editor template the same way.

Another thing to note is that it is probably not a good idea to pass in IEnumerable<> as your viewmodel. What if you need to pass other non-MedicalProduct properties to your view?

I would advocate a composite viewmodel instead, like so.

```
public class EditMedicalProductViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> MedicalProducts { get; set; }
}

public class CreateMedicalProductViewModel
{
    public MedicalProductViewModel MedicalProduct { get; set; }
}
```

In your edit view you'd do this instead

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MedicalProducts)
```

And for your create view you'd do this

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.MedicalProduct)
```

In your create method you should create a new medical product

```
return View(new CreateMEdicalProductViewModel() { MedicalProduct = new MedicalProductViewModel() } );
```

Comment: I am going to try your answer.  If I pass a single viewmodel, won't that only show one medicalProduct on the page?  I'm trying to be consistent and I am still learning how this all works.

Comment: How do I pass in a new list?  `return View(new List<MedicalProductViewModel>())`?

Comment: Please look at my updated answer on what you should do instead.

Comment: I have also added the last bit on what to pass to the Create view too!

Comment: To use your existing solution, use     `return View(new List<MedicalProductViewModel>() { new MedicalProductViewModel() });`

Comment: I will try your new updated answer, but should I perhaps put those two new classes under models\CompositeViewModel for organization?  And since I'm going to also use one of those two classes for the delete action, What should the newer more appropriate Names for the composite view Models be?

Comment: I usually have a ViewModels folder, as Models are usually database entities. In my viewmodels folder I further create folders for each controller, and the actual viewmodel class will be linked to the method. e.g. `/ViewModels/MedicalProduct/DeleteMedicalProductViewModel.cs`. You could also put your shared view model in `/ViewModels/MedicalProduct/MedicalProductViewModel.cs`

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because your model is a `IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel>`, but your editor template is for a `MedicalProductViewModel`

You could try this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>MedicalProduct</legend>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        Html.EditorFor(model => item)        
    }
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

But this will probably not format the fields quite the way you want, since it will create numerous editors. The easiest method would be to refactor your controller so that it allows editing one record at a time.

Comment: My edit view works great with MedicalProductViewModel.cshtml, and it is strongly typed to an `IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel>`.  So I don't see why that would cause the EditorTemplate not to display.  See my edit in the question to see the edit.cshtml

Comment: I tried changing the strongly typed MedicalProductViewModel to IEnumerable, and it made no difference, and the edit view generated a run time error.

Comment: There is no need to change the EditorTemplate type. EditorFor will enumerate the list and pass each item to your EditorTemplate. Check my answer and see if that works for you